# How to get harmonically growing distances from a center?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

I think this one should be asked a mathematician. I'm trying to make a vulcano plot, where the x axis expresses distance from $1$ on a $\mathrm{log2}$ scale, i.e. $[1 : \mathrm{log2}(1), 1.5 : \mathrm{log2}(1.5), \dots]$. I want to draw lines, that show the x-fold change on a normal scale, i.e. $[2^{\mathrm{log2}(1)}$, $2^{\mathrm{log2}(1.5)}, \dots]$. The requirements are that the folds should harmonically shrink/grow from the center, but the values still should be intuitive. I used $x = [0.5, 2/3, 0.8, 0.9, 1.1, 1.25, 1.5, 2]$, but somehow this doesn't look right.

[image]

My question is, why exactly is $0.9$ is farther from the center than $1.1$? What would be the right sequence to use for $x$? I tried $[\sqrt1, \sqrt2 ,\sqrt3, \dots]$ but that gave me exactly the opposite. I'm also not sure what to use for the left hand side.

Hope, that makes sense.

Comment: How did you make this graph? I don't think a software will plot 1.1 closer to 1 than 0.9. And, I don't exactly understand what you want. I guess you want to find a sequence of "simple" numbers that are close to some sequence, but I can't get what the latter sequence is. By the way, does the word "harmonic" refer to something related to the sum 1+1/2+1/3+..., or does it just mean "beautiful"?